# Ошибка при попытке выполнить map в React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

Мне нужно получить с интернета данные, с этим я разобрался - получаю, и сразу же добавляю их в состояние компонента

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получаю примерное это:

> [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object],
>   [object Object], [object Object]

Не могу приложить скрин так как показывает на телефоне.

Далее я разбиваю это все методом map, в итоге есть вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так же ошибку:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object(evalueting
>   'this.state.images.map')

Не знаю как тут быть, очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, начнем с конструктора компонента, там должен быть объявлена ваша переменная в стейте и в ней должно лежать значение `null`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    images: null // тут ничего нет в самом начале
  }

  // не забываем про `bind` метода, внутри которого используется `this`
  this.getMoviesFromAviAsync = this.getMoviesFromAviAsync.bind(this);
}
```

Далее по коду ваш обработчик на загрузку данных и установку в стейт полученных данных, там вопросов нет, кроме одного нюанса, про который я бы хотел сказать, в сучае ошибки я бы рекомендовал положить пустой массив в `images` переменную стейта:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getMoviesFromAviAsync();
}

getMoviesFromAviAsync() {
  // some code...
  .then(response) {
    this.setState({ images: data });
  }
  // some code...
  .catch(error) {
    this.setState({ images: [] });
    console.error(error);
  }
  // some code...
}
```

Всё это делается для того, чтобы потом в методе прохода по элементам массива не возникло проблем. Далее метод рендеринга, там тоже буду некоторые рекомендации:

```
render() {
  const { images } = this.state;

  // если у нас `null` - это условие сработает
  if (!images) {
    return (<p>Loading...</p>)
  }

  // предыдущее условие гарантирует, что в images не лежит `null`
  // но если `length = 0` то в это условие мы попадаем
  if (!images.length) {
    return (<p>Something went wrong or no data...</p>)
  }

  // можно быть уверенным, что в images не `null`, не `undefined` и массив не пустой
  const imgs = images.map((image, index) => {
    return (<Text key={index}>{image.user.name}</Text>);
  });

  return (<View>{imgs}</View>);
}
```

Обратите внимание на добавленное свойство `key` - если его не добавить, то React это не понравится и получите ошибки в консоли из-за того, что отрисовываете список значений и у них нет уникального поля `key`. Об этом можно почитать тут: [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Причина возникновения ошибки в вашем коде - вы попадаете в метод рендеринга несколько раз и в первые разы у вас там нет значения в стейт у переменной `images`. При изменении состояния всегда происходит ререндеринг, почитатйте следующую статейку, будет полезно: [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: к сожалению этот способ не помог, так как теперь всегда висит надпись Loading, хотя элементы давно загружены, и alert об этом сообщает